# How do you create PDFs using itextsharp and pie charts from live charts?

Tags: c#, wpf, itext, livecharts

I am working on a project with a WPF (MVVM framework) desktop application. As per need, we integrate LiveCharts in the project to show multiple charts. Now, as per requirement I have to show that multiple images into pdf. How can I generate pdf using iTextSharp?

Answer (score 1):

I found answer by myself from google and stackoverflow.
Here are the code sample.

```
var DataValue = new LiveCharts.Wpf.PieChart
            {
                DisableAnimations = true,
                Width = 600,
                Height = 387,
                Series = ViewModel.PieCollection
            };
var viewbox = new Viewbox();
            viewbox.Child = DataValue ;
            viewbox.Measure(DataValue .RenderSize);
            viewbox.Arrange(new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), DataValue .RenderSize));
            DataValue .Update(true, true);
            viewbox.UpdateLayout();
//Save as image method with chart and name of image
SaveToPng(DataValue, "image.png");
```